# Klebsiella pneumoniae and corticosteroids

Tags: bacteria, corticosteroids, pneumonia

Does anyone know why taking corticosteroids is a risk factor of a Klebsiella pneumoniae infection? Also, is it normal to find Klebsiella pneumoniae in the throat area or upper respiratory tract?

I'd appreciate your help.

EDIT: Please visit [What You Need to Know About a Klebsiella Pneumoniae Infection](https://www.healthline.com/health/klebsiella-pneumonia#risk-factors)